# Android. Textview. Dot sign is taking too much space

Tags: android, textview

I am using custom(Gotham Light) font. Textview contains date where numbers were divided by dot(.).

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDateFrom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="12.06.14"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Dot sign is taking too much space.

[image]

How to make dot take only the space it needs?

Comment: As some of here suggested `textScaleX`might help you.You might want to be careful that this attribute was added in API level 11

Comment: that may be problem with your font. try with android:text="12.06.84" or other digits

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at documentation : [public void setTextScaleX (float size)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextScaleX(float))

- Sets the extent by which text should be stretched horizontally.

Comment: tried this option, but this is making text like "zipped" which looks not so good(

Comment: try playing with the `size` value of `setTextScaleX()`, or change your font if possible, problem might be due to font type

Comment: it was because of monospace in theme

Comment: ohh... Like i said _change your font if possible, problem might be due to font type_ Great... Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this attribute android:textScaleX in your xml file

add it like this

```
android:textScaleX="0.1"
```

Comment: tried this option, but this is making text like "zipped" which looks not so good(

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 android:textScaleX
```

or different text font

```
 android:typeface="sans"
```

Comment: tried this option, but this is making text like "zipped" which looks not so good(

Comment: Try using different font?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have a problem with your font - Gotham Light. First of all - try some other font. But if you are attached to Gotham - consider checking your text formatting - try dot unicode symbols, for example: \u002E